# How does the system select questions for the newsletter?

Tags: support, newsletter

I am subscribed to the Stack Overflow newsletter and also to a few other newsletters at Stack Exchange. A newsletter contains three kind of questions:

- Top question this week
- Greatest hits from previous weeks
- Can you answer these questions?

What criteria does the system use to select questions for a newsletter?

Comment: Wait, we have a newsletter?

Comment: @Davy M: Yes, see your user profile → tab *"Settings"* → *"Newsletters"* (though it may not be that easy due to the current Imgur outage - the link to the user profile at the top of every page is currently an invisible link).

Comment: For the "Can you answer?" I have found a description in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134031